# For each con varias variables

Tags: ios, foreach

Tengo un ForEach pero quiero poner varias variables y no se como hacerlo pongo un ejemplo:

```
 struct ParametresNew {
    let paramDes: [String]
    let paramMin: [String]
    let paramMax: [String]
    }
     
    let parametreNew2 = ParametresNew(
        paramDes: ["pa1", "pa2"],
        paramMin: ["m1", "m2"],
        paramMax: ["ms1", "ms2"]
        )
     
    ForEach(parametreNew.paramDes, id: \.self) { prova in
        Text(prova)
        Text(AQUI QUIERO PONER  el valor de paramMin)
        }
```

Lo que necesitariía es que la variable parametreNew2.paramDes estuviera al lado de parametreNew2.paramMin, que en cada caja de texto tuviera por ejemplo:

```
pa1 + m1 + ms1

pa2+ m2 + ms2

pa13+ m3 + ms3
```

más o menos sería esto, y en otra línia pa2+ m2 + ms2....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes el objeto `ParametresNew`, debes usar `init` para que crees los valores. Puedes tener diferentes `init`:

1. Ejemplo de `init` con todas las variables del objeto:

   ```
    init(paramDes: String, paramMin: String, paramMax: String) {
        self.paramDes = paramDes
        self.paramMin = paramMin
        self.paramMax = paramMax
    }
   ```
2. Ejemplo de `init` solo con una variable del objeto:

   ```
    init(paramDes: String) {
        self.paramDes = paramDes
        self.paramMin = ""
        self.paramMax = ""
    }
   ```

Puedes tener los dos juntos en tu clase o estructura:

```
class ParametresNew {
    var paramDes: String
    var paramMin: String
    var paramMax: String
    
    init(paramDes: String, paramMin: String, paramMax: String) {
        self.paramDes = paramDes
        self.paramMin = paramMin
        self.paramMax = paramMax
    }
    
    init(paramDes: String) {
        self.paramDes = paramDes
        self.paramMin = ""
        self.paramMax = ""
    }
}
```

Para el ejemplo creas una primera variable que va a ser de tipo `ParametresNew` como Array:

```
var one = [ParametresNew]()
//Agregas a la variable el objeto con todos los valores de las variables
one.append(ParametresNew(paramDes: "pa1", paramMin: "m1", paramMax: "ms1"))
one.append(ParametresNew(paramDes: "pa2", paramMin: "m2", paramMax: "ms2"))

//Recorres el objeto
for val in one {
    print(val.paramDes + " " + val.paramMin + " " + val.paramMax)
    //Puedes modificar los valores
    //val.paramMin = "50.0"
}
```

Te imprime:

> pa1 m1 ms1

> pa2 m2 ms2

Para el otro ejemplo creas otra variable del mismo tipo:

```
var two = [ParametresNew]()
//Agregas solo el primer valor de la variable
two.append(ParametresNew(paramDes: "pa3"))

//Recorres el array (Puedes modificar los valores porque los otros se crean vacíos)
for val in two {
    val.paramMax = "12.5"
    val.paramMin = "31.3"
    print(val.paramDes + " " + val.paramMin + " " + val.paramMax)
}
```

Te imprime:

> pa3 31.3 12.5